# Allow a user to add SharePoint calendar event to their Oulook calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

We have an event calendar on a SharePoint site. The calendar has several events that occur at different locations and days.  We want users to be able to select an event on the calendar and have the option to automatically have that event added to their Outlook calendar.  Any suggestions.  Everything I am finding on line is about viewing a SharePoint calendar in Outlook which is not what I am after.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do what you are asking.  But if you do choose to view the SharePoint calendar in your Outlook, you can drag & drop a copy of an event into your Outlook calendar.  Then disconnect (or don't) the SharePoint shared calendar.